# Activity doesn't save info into MySQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent

I have one reservation form which must save information to `MySQL` database. On first Axtivity user fill the form then whit intent I save the information and passit to second activity where is the button save. When I click button save nothing goes to database.
This is activity 1

```
static String Name;
static String Email;
static String Phone;
static String Comment;
static String DateTime;
static String numberOfPeople;

private EditText editText1, editText3, editText2, editText4, datePicker, editText5; //, txtTime;
private Button btnMenues, btnTimePicker, btnCalendar;
CustomDateTimePicker custom;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation);
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker)).setText(calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + year
                                    + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min
                                    + " " + AM_PM);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    custom.showDialog();
                }
});           

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personName);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personPhone);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personEmail);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personComment);
    datePicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueWithReservation);

    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Reservation.this, ReservationSecond.class);
            String Name = editText1.getText().toString();
            String Email = editText2.getText().toString();
            String Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
            String Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
            String DateTime = datePicker.getText().toString();
            String numberOfPeople = editText5.getText().toString();

            intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
            intent.putExtra("Email", Email);
            intent.putExtra("Phone", Phone);
            intent.putExtra("Comment", Comment);
            intent.putExtra("DateTime", DateTime);
            intent.putExtra("numberOfPeople", numberOfPeople);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This is Activity 2

```
String getName;
String getEmail;
String getPhone;
String getComment;
String getDateTime;
String getnumberOfPeople;

private Button btnMenues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation_second);

    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);

    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                getName = extras.getString("Name");
                getEmail = extras.getString("Email");
                getPhone = extras.getString("Phone");
                getComment = extras.getString("Comment");
                getDateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
                getnumberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
                Log.e("err", getName + " " + getEmail + " " + getPhone + " " + getComment + " " + getDateTime + " " + getnumberOfPeople );
            }   

            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);

            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }); 
}

class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String getNameToData, String getEmailData, String getPhoneData,
            String getCommentData, String getDateTimeData, String getnumberOfPeopleData) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://link.to.site/saveReservation.php");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", getNameToData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", getEmailData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", getPhoneData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", getCommentData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateTime", getDateTimeData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfPeople", getnumberOfPeopleData));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(getName, getEmail, getPhone, getComment, getDateTime, getnumberOfPeople );
        return null;
    }

}
```

I've put in second activity in intent part log to check `Log.e("err", getName + " " + getEmail + " " + getPhone + " " + getComment + " " + getDateTime + " " + getnumberOfPeople );` and in `LogCat` I see this error when button for save into DB is clicked

```
11-08 17:04:44.654: E/err(1112): Test Test@myEmail.com 33733721 Hello 26/11/2014, 4:50 PM 3
```

This is xml for the first activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/NameForReservation"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="25" />     

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/ContactPhone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="16" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/CustomerEmailContact"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="50" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/CustomerCommentar"
            android:maxLength="100" />


    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:id="@+id/btnCalendar" 
        android:text="@string/ReservationDate"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.27"
        android:inputType="datetime" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberOfPeople"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/numberOfPeople" />       
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/continueWithReservation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/reservationContinue" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea what I miss here?

UPDATE `php` file from server side

```
<?php
$icon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if(!$icon)
{
    die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_erroe());
}
mysql_select_db("db", $icon)or die("database selection error");
echo json_encode($data);

$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Comment=$_POST['Comment'];
$DateTime=$_POST['DateTime'];
$numberOfPeople=$_POST['numberOfPeople'];
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bucharest"); // time zone
    $DateTime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (Name, Phone, Email, Comment, DateTime, numberOfPeople)
         VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Comment', '$DateTime', '$numberOfPeople')",$icon);
mysql_close($icon);
```

Comment: can you log what is passed into your php file and check your apache log to see if anaything is wrong ?

Comment: what is the HttpResponse you get? This is strictly done in the server you have, because there is nothing wrong in your Android code as far as I can see.

Comment: @goro why do you take so much of time to respond

Comment: Post your php code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed single quotes '$DateTime'

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (Name, Phone, Email, Comment, DateTime, numberOfPeople) VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Comment', '$DateTime', '$numberOfPeople')");
```

mysql_query is deprecated Dont use it in new projects. Try mysqli_ or PDO

And in your php  put it above the query

```
         date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); // choose your time zone
         $DateTime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Well thank you for that. Now at least is saving something in DB but why datetime that is saved is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: If I change field `DateTime` in DB to `timestamp` is same.

Comment: Reason is you have used comma in your date. And more over it should be in 2014-11-31 22:00:00 format

Comment: You mean here `"/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + year
                                    + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min
                                    + " " + AM_PM);`

Comment: In db column is `datetime` I've also put what you gave me but doesn't matter what time and date choose always save the current date.

Comment: In mysql datetime column should be set to datetime..... And you create a date time manually in php. I have edited my answer

Comment: I've made column to `datetime`. Also I put what you tell in you answer. When I click save in app in DB I get current tyme i.e system time date and time instead what I choose in the app.

Comment: Did you put above it above mysql_query or not

Comment: Yes, check in my question I've edited the part with `php` code to see what is look like now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64571/discussion-between-indra-and-goro).